# возврат к началу кусочка кода

Tags: java

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class help {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello. Enter \"Java\"");
          Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
          String testJava = (String) str.nextLine();
    
         if (testJava != "java") {
                System.out.println("Good");
    }       else {
                System.out.println("No good. Please try again");
    }
    // тут я хочу чтоб если сработал else, то его возращало к началу
  }
 }
```

Comment: Используйте циклы, они предназначены именно для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо условного оператора пишете цикл ожидания `while`, *пока не будет введено "Java", выводить сообщение о повторном вводе;*.

Также для проверки равенства строк вместо операторов сравнения `==` / `!=` следует использовать `String::equals` (с учётом регистра) / `String::equalsIgnoreCase` (без учёта регистра)

```java
System.out.println("Hello. Enter \"Java\"");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String testJava;

while (!"java".equalsIgnoreCase(testJava = scan.nextLine())) {
    System.out.println("No good. Please try again");
}
System.out.println("Good");
```